# SVN Not a working copy

Tags: svn

I'm grinding my teeth here, trying to figure out the problem to this. I've done nothing but search for a few hours on how to do this properly, and everything gives me the same answer:

```
svnadmin create dir
cd dir
svn checkout https://path.to.server
svn status
svn update
svn add /path/to/dir/
svn commit -m "type message here"
```

No matter how many times I do this (I'm running Ubuntu 10.10, by the way), I keep getting a "path/to/dir/ is not a working copy". The path is just a link to a solution file and some .cs files in c# that I code in monodevelop. What's the problem here? Am I missing something?

The checkout works fine, but everything else is just giving me an error.

Comment: If you are really running that sequence of commands, you are creating a new repository and then checking out some code to the repository data directory. Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

`svnadmin create dir` is to be used only to create a repo. Not a working copy. Don't use it.

Secondly, when you checkout, it would have created a folder within `dir`, cd into that and then do the rest of the commands. Or, use:

```
svn checkout https://path.to.server .
```

( note the . at end)

Comment: so, you're saying I should cd into the dir that holds my files, checkout using the server link, and then cd into the directory created from that checkout, and then do svn status, update, add, etc.

If that's the case, when I add the file, should I specify the path to the directory of the files, or can I just do "svn add *", or something along those lines?

Comment: @Holland - First of all, I would like you to get some basic info about using svn, working copy etc. This is a Q&A site, not a tutorial site. Try, `svn checkout https://path.to.server .` like I said, and the rest of the commands should work fine.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've actually tried getting basic info about working copy and such. I've even searched this site, and while I've found people with similar issues, their cases in particular weren't exactly what I was experiencing.